# positioning elements within a div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple website that I've made from scratch. I got confused with the layout of my header:

- H1 title
- Text line
- Logo
- Menu (coding from w3school)

These four are within my div header. I'd like to be able to position them wherever I want within the div. The issue I have is that I'm not sure what coding to use for this (margin, position: relative or absolute, padding, top:, right:, etc.).

I've tried all kinds of combinations but it seems they never position where I want them and they mess up each others' position: the menu loses full width, the logo I can't get nicely with same space between top and right of header div, the H1 and tag don't seem to respond to the pixels I set, and so on.

Could someone please take the time and have a look at my code and come with a suggestion how to make this layout stable?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
 }

#page {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 30px auto;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }

#header {
 height: 377px;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0px 0px;
 }

#header a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 
#header ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #3399FF;
 position: relative;
 top: 264px;
 }
 
#header li {
 float: left;
 }
 
#header li a {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

#header li a.active {
    background-color: gray;
    }

#header li a:hover:not(.active){
 background-color: #3366CC;
 }

.p1 {
 font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace; 
    font-size: 20px;
 position: relative;
    top: 28px;
 left: 50px;
 }  
 
.p2 {
    font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
 font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
 left: 200px;
 }

.logo {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top: 8px;
 right: 8px;
 }
 
#content {
 position: relative;
 top: 12px;
 left: 10px;
 }
 
#footer {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 padding-bottom: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: #D3D3D3 0.5px solid;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">
<img class="logo" src="images/logo-d.png">
<span class="p1"><a href="http://www.finasteride-kopen.nl"><h1>This is my H1 Title</h1></a></span>
<span class="p2">"This is going to be my tag under H1"</span>
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="">Link menu</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link menu 5</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<h1>H1 Title of the page content<h1>
<p></p>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<p></p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
The footer of the page
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion: try to think of a webpage as list of objects rather than a poster etc. Screen sizes vary (desktop/mobile) and you should use relative widths and positions to ensure responsiveness of your site. I'm sure you can find a better template to work on.

Second suggestion: If you DO wish to position an element "anywhere" this is an example of correct use of positioning:

```
<style>
.floatingdiv {
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
}
</style>
<div class="floatingdiv">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a template. I made it myself (hence the issues). This code looks the most familiar to me and I will try. But I have used position style and it seemed to affect the position of the other content within the div header.

Answer (score 0):

Put the contents of the header in an Unordered list as so. If you are using a responsive framework like Bootstrap, this will be completely different - but since you did not specify, here is an example without a framework.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header>
<ul>
  <li><h1>Your Title</h1></li>
  <li><p>some line of text you wanted</p></li>
  <li class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="yourlogo.png" /></a></li>
  <li class="spacer"></li>
  <li><a href="somepage.html>Some Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="somepage.html>Some Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="somepage.html>Some Page</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header li{
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: inline;
}

#header li.spacer{
    width:10%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a case of structuring the divs correctly, as Holle points out, this is a list of objects rather than a poster. I think the main issue you are having in positioning is that you're foundation structure within your html isn't beneficial for manipulating.

I would recommend having a container div for each section and then further divs or other content within those. i.e.

```
<div id="headerContainer">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <img id="logo" src="myImagePath">
</div>
<div id="navigation">
        <!-- Navigation Bar, your UL list items -->
</div>
<div id="pageContent">
        <!-- More content... <img>s, <p>s, <h1>s, probably more divs to structure the content etc-->
</div>
```

I hope that helps, if you want a suggestion, take a look a DevTips youTube channel, he's great at explaining the design and structuring stages when building a website.

Also, in terms of positioning, check out flexbox froggy (google it), just be aware the browser support isn't fantastic before you jump in.

Cheers,
James

Comment: Thanks for the references. Do you recommend any text books for self-study?

Comment: No problem, A guy I work with used this - https://www.amazon.co.uk/HTML-CSS-Design-Build-Sites/dp/1118008189 and I've looked at it, it really really simple and explains things well.

Comment: No problem, A guy I work with used this - [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HTML-CSS-Design-Build-Sites/dp/1118008189) and, it really avoids a lot of jargon, it's simple and explains things well, also makes a great reference guide. Personally, when I first started learning, I found a few resources very useful, it is super important to get the basics down and make sure you really understand (not how to write the code, the understanding about how the code works), seriously, write it and just ask on a forum for feedback on how you could do things better, people's criticism is better than a book imo